# What does the Acronym "Spitter" stand for?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Been reading up on Spring Boot JPA.  The term "Spitter" gets referenced many times.  I know what a Spitter does.  However, what does this acronym stand for?  I know this question is not techie but it is bugging me and I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Cheers...

Comment: Are you certain (in the use case you are searching for) that it is an acronym?

Comment: Well, it's an unusual name and looks like it is some sort of acronym or play  of a combination of word abbreviations.

Comment: I guess it's a term that defines the output of database search.  "The search spits out a result that is stored in a spitter object".  Usually Java architects are a little more creative with object names.

Comment: 'Spittr' is the example twitter clone web app from Spring in Action, 4th edition by Craig Walls, published by Manning Publications.

Comment: I agree with your finding about Spitter. I found this application from a google search just like you did.  However, this is an application that mimics twitter using a database -- SPring Implementing twiTTER application.  However, when you are using JDBC, Hybernate, or JPA, a Spitter is a data object that contains the result of a database search.  I was just wondering what the acronym means.  Maybe its not an acronym and maybe just a term -- A Spitter is a data object that contains the result of a database search and "Spitted" into the object.  But I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing some ideas from Twitter and implementing them in Spring gives the
application a working title: Spitter.